# How can I get data from joined table with a certain condition?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables named Users, Question & Answers. I retrieved all the answers from the Answers table for a particular question. Now I need to get all the users name who answered the question.

This is how my controller look like now :

```
    public function show($id)
    {
        $question['question'] = Question::find($id);

        // fetch all answers where answer table question_id == question_id

        $question['answers'] = Answer::where('question_id', $question_id)->get();

        //fetch user data who answered the question

        $question['users'] = ?

        return $question;

    }
```

Table relationships are:

#### In User

```
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
```

#### In Question

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }


    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasmany(Answer::class);
    }
```

### In Answer

```
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

In View I need:
Question
  + All answers of the question with the User name who answered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eager load the `answers.user` relationship on the question.

```
Question::with('answers.user')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Which will retrieve:

1. The question
2. With an array of answers
3. With a user belonging to each answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a dynamic scope into `User` class which will retrieve users only if the question is found among its relationship:

```php
    public function scopeOfQuestion($query, $questionId)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('questions', function ($query) use ($questionId) {
            $query->where('id', $questionId);
        });
    }
```

```php
public function show($id)
    {
        $question = Question::find($id);
        $users = User::ofQuestion($question->getKey())->get();
    }
```